# get param from response

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i enter the link like this : `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a2803%2fDefault.aspx` , the server will return me an url like this: `http://localhost:2803/Default.aspx?code=ABCDEFGH`.

I want to perform those action from server. i have used HttpWebRequest.getResponse() to try to the code from the returned request but couldnt. 
Could you tell me how to call it from server and get the " code" parameter from response.
i had a try with the code above, but seem not work. if i use response.redirect, i can get Request.QueryString. however, doing like this makes my page reload one more unnecesarry time

```
var link = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a2803%2fDefault.aspx";

    var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(link);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Encoding rEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
```

Comment: can you please provide some code of what you have attempted?

Comment: Did you try `Request.QueryString["variable"]` ?

Answer (score 2):

in Default.aspx.cs you cann access the value `ABCDEFGH` this way:

```
string CodeValue = Request.QueryString["code"];
```